# How to show that det(A)≤1?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $A = (a_{ij})_n$ where $a_{ij} \ge 0$ for $i,j=1,2,\ldots,n$ and $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \le 1$ for $i = 1,2,\ldots,n$.
>   Show that $|\det(A)| \le 1$.

Should I use the definition of matrix:

$$\det(A)=\sum \textrm{sgn}(\sigma)a_{1,\sigma(1)}a_{2,\sigma(2)}...a_{n,\sigma(n)}$$

I don't understand what is $a_{i,\sigma(i)}$ ? Where $i=1,2,
\ldots,n$. Or is there another way to solve it?

Answer (score 6):

You can prove that by induction on the dimension $n$ of the matrix.
It is clearly true for $n = 1$.

Now assume that $n > 1$ and the statement is true for all matrices
of dimension  $(n-1, n-1)$. Using the
[Laplace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace.27s_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix), you have
$$
\det(A) = \sum_{j=1}^n  a_{1j} \det(A_j)
$$
where $A_1, ..., A_n$ are submatrices of the dimension $(n-1, n-1)$ 
which have the same properties as $A$: All entries are positive
and the row sums are less or equal to one, so 
$|\det(A_j)| \le 1$ for $j=1,..., n$.

Then
$$
|\det(A)| \le \sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j} |\det(A_j)|
 \le \sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j} \le 1
$$

Comment: But how can we take |det(Aj)|≤1 directly? It should has more explaination.

Comment: @SoksereyMan: It is a proof by "mathematical induction". $A_j$ is a "smaller" matrix with the same properties, therefore you can assume the statement to be true for $A_j$.

Comment: @Martin R: Nice ! This seems to work for the permanent too, which in this case is clearly larger than the absolute value of the determinant.

Comment: @SoksereyMan Do you or do you not need to use Leibniz' formula?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the sneaky approach:

First note, we can decide whether we want the column-sums or the row-sums to be $\leq 1$, since we can of course transpose our matrix. I want the column-sums to be $\leq 1$.

The $1$-norm $\| \cdot \|_1$ on $\mathbb C^n$ induces via

$$\| A \| := \sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_1}$$

the column-sum norm on the $n \times n$-matrices. The assumption is precisely $\|A\| \leq 1$ then.

For any $x \in \mathbb C^n$ we have $\|Ax\|_1 \leq \|A\|\|x\|_1 \leq \|x\|_1$. This holds in particular for any eigenvector of $A$, which shows that any (possibly complex) eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ satisfies $|\lambda| \leq 1$. This shows the assertion, since the determinant is obtained as the product of all eigenvalues.

---

We also have a geometric reason: The edges of the unit cubes are mapped into the unit cube, hence any convex combination of them is mapped into the unit cube. This shows $A[0,1]^n \subset [0,1]^n$. Since the determinant is geometrically defined to be the volume of the image of the unit cube, we immediately get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. Use Leibniz formula for determinants. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n.C2.A0.C3.97.C2.A0n_matrices) for an example.

As for the a's (from the link above, formatting mine):

> Here the sum is computed over all permutations σ of the set {1, 2, ..., n}. A permutation is a function that reorders this set of integers. The value in the ith position after the reordering σ is denoted $σ_i$. For example, for n = 3, the original sequence 1, 2, 3 might be reordered to σ = [2, 3, 1], with $σ_1 = 2, σ_2 = 3$, and $σ_3 = 1$.

Comment: Maybe it's hard for me to understand because I learned very little about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just take modulus the determinant expression you wrote. Note each term on the right under sum can be bounded by using G.M. $\le$ A.M.

Comment: Wouldn't that require that $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{j\sigma(j)} \le 1$ ? Can one conclude that from $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \le 1$ ?

Comment: Is that would. Actually I didn't notice ur ans.